# Visual Studio EditorConfig settings do not show up in Error List

Tags: visual-studio-2022, editorconfig

I have redefined some of the Visual Studio editorconig settings to treat certain rules as warnings and/or errors.

For example these:

[image]

The issue I have is that after storing the settings I would expect that I will get warnings/errors in the "Error List" but this is not the case.

If I force a certain rule to be throw an error nothing happens. I can even compile without any errors or warnings I've set.

I tested these settings with Visal Studio 2022 Community Edition and also with Professional but non of them seem to check these settings.

Does anybody know what could cause this? Is there maybe another setting which "activates" the validation of these styleguide rules?

Any help is very appreciated!

Comment: I can't seem to reproduce: https://i.stack.imgur.com/eMOLN.png  it still lets me build, but it reports it in the error list and shows up in the editor.

Comment: Actually, it looks like you are modifying this via the Tools window.  Try modifying the .editorconfig file it self - should open in an editor tab, so like: https://i.stack.imgur.com/3Hv2i.png

Comment: @TimothyG. I've added the editorconfig file to the solution and I see the same setting as in the tools window. Changing it in the editorconfig file does not having any effect. What VS version do you have?

Comment: Visual Studio 17.5.0 Preview 1